# Not able to make payments on the aws account

Tags: amazon-web-services

Everytime I login to my AWS account to make payment I am getting the message to enter the OTP, but also getting the message that payment is failed(PLease see the below screenshot)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i93Yy.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question for AWS Support related to a specific account and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. We are not Amazon, and therefore have no ability to look at the details of your account to answer any questions or resolve any issues with that account. Contact AWS Support directly via their site.

Comment: Reading the screenshot, sorry for stating the obvious, looks like either the registered address of your card is not the same as your AWS Billing Address, or there is a browser compatibility issue and you should try another browser.